# How do i continue running my program after encountering exception in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql, goto

I have written a PL/SQL code to to print only records greater than id=4. I used a goto statement in the program, which is not detected in exception. Please help me continue the program after encountering the exception.
My code is

```
declare
    cursor cur is select * from student;
    c student%rowtype;
    lt3 exception;
    PRAGMA
    exception_init(lt3,-77);
begin
    open cur;
    loop
        <<backup>>
        fetch cur into c;
        if c.id < 4 then
            raise lt3;
        else
            dbms_output.put_line(c.name);
        end if;
    end loop;
    close cur;
exception
    when lt3 then
    dbms_output.put_line('Exception encountered');
    goto backup;
end;
/
```

Where should i change?

I got the error at

```
ERROR at line 24:
ORA-06550: line 24, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'BACKUP' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 24, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: do you really need to use the exception?

Comment: @brenners1302 My point is to use exception, and would like to continue execution after the hit.

Comment: Why not just change your cursor to only select students with an id greater than 4?

Comment: lol, i asked if you really need an exception and you answered your point is to use exception?then you accepted an answer that doesnt tackle the use of exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use `goto` in `cursor`, cursor will be closed, hence you cannot achieve the expected behaviour.

From [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/goto_statement.htm)

> If you use the GOTO statement to exit a cursor FOR loop prematurely,
>   the cursor is closed automatically. The cursor is also closed
>   automatically if an exception is raised inside the loop.

One thing you can do is to use [`continue`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/continue_statement.htm#LNPLS01360) , `break`, `exit` in the loop to control the execution

```
open cur;
loop
    fetch cur into c;
    if c.id < 4 then
          continue;
    else
          dbms_output.put_line(c.name);
    end if;
end loop;
close cur;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using goto statement in any code if you can.

Below code should achieve what you are trying to do. I don't have access in database so there might be some incorrect syntax.

```
declare
    cursor cur is select * from student;
    c student%rowtype;
    lt3 exception;
    PRAGMA
    exception_init(lt3,-77);
begin
    open cur;
    loop
    begin
            fetch cur into c;
            if c.id < 4 then
        raise lt3;
            else
                dbms_output.put_line(c.name);
            end if;
    exception
        when lt3 then
        dbms_output.put_line('Exception encountered');
    end;
    end loop;
    close cur;
exception
    when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('other error encountered');
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should select id>4 to avoid exception.

Goto will not work this way. You need to use continue or break for execution control.